# Update default version for easy install

Tags: python, pypi

When I use `easy_install <package>` it would install the 1.0.0 version of my package, although, I already pushed the version 1.0.1 of this package to PyPi recently.

Is there a way to update the version `easy_install` grabs by default so that I can make sure that people get the most recent version automatically?

**Update:**
The link to the package is:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPrind

and the easy_install yields:

```
sebastian ~> easy_install pyprind
Searching for pyprind
Best match: PyPrind 1.0.0
Adding PyPrind 1.0.0 to easy-install.pth file
```

Comment: It should do this automatically. Can you provide the link to your package's PyPI page?

Comment: That's what I assumed, too. But then I got this feeling of missing something... (PS: provided the package link above), thanks for your help!

Comment: Works for me. (It downloaded v1.0.1.) Keep in mind, previous users will need to run `easy_install --upgrade pyprind` (or alternatively specify a specific version or upgrade to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work now. Maybe it just took some time for the changes to propagate on the mirrored servers. I write this to close this question. Thanks for your help.